# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using the latest android studio build 1.1 ,since i want to import an eclipse project that needs NDK .i installed NDK and set the NDK location in the `local.properties`.The problem is when i try to run the project 2 errors are displayed they are

```
1) Error:(199) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
2)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\vishal\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

any solution?

Comment: You should be able to get the output from the ndk-build command from your gradle logs, with a more explicit error, so we can have more information to help you.

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk
C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\DELTA-Software-master\AppPatcher\app\src\main\jni\bspatch.c: In function 'bspatch':
C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\DELTA-Software-master\AppPatcher\app\src\main\jni\bspatch.c:82:2: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "bspatch.c", argv[0]);
  ^

Comment: Same error i am getting.how to solve this issue in android studio?

Answer (score 20):

Try adding this to the `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets.main {
   jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This solved my problem:

- If you don't have th JNI directory in your project, create it:

[image]

- Go to the new JNI directory that you just created. It should be in`{approot}\app\src\main\jni`

[image]

- Create an empty *.c file

[image]

- Add the following code to your `app/gradle.build` file, in the android section. It should look like this:

  ```
  android {
      ...
      sourceSets.main {
          jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
          jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

May be this is [known NDK bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937). Try to add empty .c file to your jni dir (like empty.c).