# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' when trying to compile Android Studio project with NDK source code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

No matter how many tutorials I followed, every time I try to make a project containing C source files gradle outputs the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\svprdga\Downloads\android-ndk-r10d_x86\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

For example, I downloaded the following tutorial, which also throws the same error:

https://github.com/mpospelov/android-studio-ndk-hello-world

I have seen the following questions, but I not understand exactly what I am supposed to do:

[execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' failed to run this command ndk-build.cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk)
[Can't build project with android-ndk and Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052564/cant-build-project-with-android-ndk-and-ndroid-studio)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28810873
"Try to add empty .c file to your jni dir (like empty.c)". It worked in my case - Android Studio 1.1.0 with android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The version code of compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion should be consistent in the module build.gradle file.
eg.

```
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 20 
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    ...
}
```