# Getting error: Execution failed for task : myApp:compileDebugNdk'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

Hi I am trying to run an app created with Cocos2d-x 2.5 with Android Studio but I keep getting this error when running the project:

> :myApp:compileDebugNdk AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"*** Android NDK:
>   Aborting...    . 
>   Stop.","sourcePath":"/mypath/ndk/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/add-application.mk","position":{"startLine":199},"original":""}
>
> FAILED  Execution failed for task ':myApp:compileDebugNdk'.

Building works ok. I have Android Studio 1.1.0 and a Mac with OS X Yosemite 10.10.

Do you guys have any idea what could be wrong?

I have seen a similar error being discussed here [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' when trying to compile Android Studio project with NDK source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816126/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-when-trying-to-compile-android)

but the solution doesn't work for me (created an empty .c file in the jni folder). It looks like that is something that happens on Windows and I use Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it adding this to the build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets.main {
   jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add ndk path in your local.properties file.
Check this tutorial here :
http://aprogrammersday.blogspot.in/2015/02/cocos2d-x-game-development-in-android.html

Comment: Please don't just link to external sites for an answer. Find what's relevant from that page and then explain it here for the asker, you can then cite that page as a source.

Answer (score 0):

1.set path for android ndk
2.add ndk.dir=ndk_path in local.properties file
3.add the following in gradle file

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

Thats solves my problem.